# Windows Server 2019 "Server for NFS" UID/GID mapping with Auth_SYS

Tags: linux, mapping, mount, nfs

I have a Windows Server 2019 installation with an LDAP instance (nfsmappingstore) for nfs mapping.  I created this with the powershell cmdlet Install-NfsMappingStore.

To illustrate, here is a list of the users in that store, and a test of one user:
[image]

I have an NFS Share setup as illustrated here:
[image]

When I turn on the option circled called "Enable unmapped user access", with the sub-option "Allow unmapped user Unix access (by UID/GID)", then I can go to my uBuntu 18.04 machine and mount that successfully with the command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs server:/AutoProv mnt
```

I can then see the files and folders in the share.

However, when I turn that option off, wishing to actually use the mapped user functionality, I get the error:

```
root@br-dv-ss-l01:/home/steve# mount -vvvv -t nfs server:/AutoProv mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Apr  2 18:28:11 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=10.200.225.1,clientaddr=10.200.225.104'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=10.200.225.1,clientaddr=10.200.225.104'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting server:/AutoProv
root@br-dv-ss-l01:/home/steve#
```

I think this means that the uid/gid was not really sent or interpreted by Windows Server 2019.  Looking at the event logs on the server, it seems to indicate that it is happy and reading the LDAP instance OK, and the Test cmdlet gives no errors.

[image]

The one possible altered thing I could think to do that seemed to cause a very slightly different effect was to add the "-o nfsvers=3" to the mount command.   When I did that, the share did actually mount, but the NFS server refused to let me see anything inside of the share:
[image]

Can someone guide me as to how to investigate this issue further?   At this time I do not know how to verify what the Windows Server is getting as far as UID/GID, so I really don't know which side of this the issue is on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, we never got any answer on this.   LDAP option appears not to work at all.   However, the passwd, group file mapping option works great, and we switched to that.

The files have to be named 'group' and 'passwd' lowercase with no extension. They have to be placed in 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc'. Syntax for 'group':

```
machinename\PodGroup:x:2501:2500,3500
machinename\MyLocalWindowsGroup:x:2502,3500
domain\ACLname:x:2503:0,2500
```

or generally:

groupname:x:GID:UID1,UID2,etc....

Essentially this is the same mapping that Linux uses as described here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/etcgroup-file-explained/

So you define a local group on your Windows Server that is running NFS and reference that in the first entry of the line, or use a domain ACL group there. Each 'column' of each line is separated by colons. The second entry 'x' is a description field I think and not used.  Third is the GID you want the windows group to be mapped to.

For passwd:

```
domain\stevesims:x:0:0:Root User,,,:c:\users\stevesims
domain\johndoe:x:2500:2501:Pod User,,,:c:\users\johndoe
domain\janedoe:x:3500:2501:Pod User,,,:C:\users\janedoe
```

or generally:

```
username:x:UID:GID:desc,,,:WindowsPathToItsProfile
```

Once these files are in place on the NFS Server you *must* restart the NFS Server service or it will not reread the file.

After it is restarted, it will read the file, and if a Linux machine writes a file to the NFS Server, it will be treated as if it has the permissions of the matching Windows account or group from these files.

Comment: Am I right by saying, that you got Auth_Sys working with local passwd, group mapping? Can you show these files syntax? I can't get it to work, my linux client still gets permission denied :(

Comment: Sure, see my edits to the answer above.

Comment: I might should have reversed the order and described passwd first, since the last column of the lines in the group file is a comma separated list of UID's